# Unable to send large data in Jquery ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Hi I am developing MVC4 application. I am saving values to Database. I am getting below error.

```
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
```

I am making ajax call and sending data as Json as below.

```
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        url: '/UploadDocument/SubmitDoc?JsonValue=' + JSON.stringify(SaveUpload) + '&gridData=' + strOrderArr,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {
                        'VerificationToken': forgeryId
                    },
                    success: function (response) {}
});
```

Web.config

```
 <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

May i know am i following good approach to handle above scenario when posting huge data to database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Niranjan, build your web service to accept data through the request body and not the URL

Comment: Thank you for your message. May I know what kind of web service? How to implement in the above scenario? May I have some links of sites?

Comment: I already put maxAllowedContentLength? does this diffrent then maxQueryStringLength  in web.config?

Comment: Thank you Div. I will go through the link that you have given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **POST** Request yet you're passing data in Query string!

Pass data in `Data` parameter:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: '/UploadDocument/SubmitDoc',
        data:  JSON.stringify({ JsonValue: SaveUpload, gridData:strOrderArr }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
        'VerificationToken': forgeryId
        },
        success: function (response) {}
});
```

Comment: This is really worked for me. I just tried as above. I succesfully executed by sending large amount of data and it worked fine for me. Thank you very mch Jerry Goyal.

Comment: I changed data as  data: JSON.stringify({JsonValue: JSON.stringify(SaveUpload), gridData:strOrderArr}),